# Error handling response: TypeError: self.processResponse is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

Getting this error in the Devtool(Console).

**Error handling response: TypeError: self.processResponse is not a function**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Issue Solved:** It seems like due to the (What runs) chrome extension, this issue is occurring.

[image]

Comment: Had the same problem and deleting the 'What runs' extension had solved it.

Comment: Same for me. Still not fixed

Comment: @Mulli - just check if you have installed any chrome extension called "What runs".

Comment: @AnupDhal. Yes. This was causing the problem

Answer (score 5):

just by simply deactivating WhatRuns chrome extension, resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue running a site internally.  Seems like that extension needs to be updated.

Error handling response: TypeError: self.processResponse is not a function
at chrome-extension://cmkdbmfndkfgebldhnkbfhlneefdaaip/js/notification.js:154:10

and this references index.html line 1 as the source of the error pointing back to the notification.js file called by that extension.

and this was on a bare html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Javascript Debug Challenge</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <!-- <script src="/part-1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <!-- <script src="/part-2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <!-- <script src="/part-3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <!-- <script src="/part-4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <script src="/part-5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32545668)