# Using SCSS with the variable and Javascript could't read my variable and complained about setProperty

Tags: javascript, html, sass

It supposed to show two different images by moving the slider to the left or right.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsvbZ.png)

However, i got this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J75WW.png)

Seems like the setProperty isnt working properly as I wished and I tried to use plain CSS they complained about

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n84u4.png)

So probably the javascript isnt working properly?

Does anyone know what's the problem is? thanks

HTML

```
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="image-container">
                <img class="image-before slider-image"
                    src="/img/before.png" alt="before image">
                <img class="image-after slider-image"
                src="/img/after.png" alt="before image">
            </div>
            <input type="range" min="0" step="10" max="100" value="50" class="slider" aria-label="Percentage of before photo shown" />
            <div class="slider-line">
                <div class="slider-button" aria-hidden="true">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 256 256"><rect width="256" height="256" fill="none"></rect><line x1="128" y1="40" x2="128" y2="216" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="16"></line><line x1="96" y1="128" x2="16" y2="128" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="16"></line><polyline points="48 160 16 128 48 96" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="16"></polyline><line x1="160" y1="128" x2="240" y2="128" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="16"></line><polyline points="208 96 240 128 208 160" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="16"></polyline></svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

SCSS

```
*,
*::after,
*::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

$white : #dddddd;
$position: 50%;
$box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px hsl(0, 50%, 2%, .5);

img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}

main {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}


.container {
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    position: $position;
}

.image-container {
    max-width: 800px;
    max-height: 90vh;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;

}

.slider-image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: left;
}

.image-before {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    width: $position;
}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    // for firefox
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    &:focus-visible ~ .slider-button{
        outline: 5px solid black;
        outline-offset: 3px;
    }
}

// .slider:focus-visible ~ .slider-button {
//     outline: 5px solid black;
//     outline-offset: 3px;
// }

.slider-line {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    width: 0.2rem;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: $white;
    z-index: 10;
    left: $position;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    pointer-events: none;
  
}

.slider-button {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: $white;
    padding: .5rem;
    border-radius: 100vw;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: $position;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 100;
    box-shadow: $box-shadow;
}
```

JS

```
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

document.querySelector(".slider").addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  container.style.setProperty(`$position`), `${e.target.value}%`;
});
```

Comment: Maybe you want to try another approach? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_image_compare

Comment: Welcome! Can you [please read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732) about the problems with images of text and then edit your question to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're closing the parenthesis pair of `setProperty` early. `${e.target.value}%` is the second argument of this function call.
Also, the property set, is `position` (just as it is in CSS), not `$position`

```
document.querySelector(".slider").addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  container.style.setProperty(`position`, `${e.target.value}%`);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes to the parenthesis was misplaced!!! 

but no to the $ as i was using SASS. 

I also figured out SASS is a CSS preprocessor, which means that all SASS specific information disapears when you compile it to CSS.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787845/how-to-control-sass-variable-with-javascript

I found a solution. :D

Answer (score 0):

The answer was already solved :

> **It seems like due to the (What runs) chrome extension, this issue is occurring.**

[Error handling response: TypeError: self.processResponse is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72998217/error-handling-response-typeerror-self-processresponse-is-not-a-function)

If it didn't help you, just tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out two problems in here. First is the parenthesis closed wrongly. Second is SASS is a CSS preprocessor, which means that all SASS specific information disapears when you compile it to CSS. [How to control Sass Variable with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787845/how-to-control-sass-variable-with-javascript)

hence, here is my solution

scss

```
    $position: 50%;

.container {
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    --position: var(--position, $position);}

.image-before {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    width: var(--position, $position);
}

.slider-line {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    width: 0.2rem;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: $white;
    z-index: 10;
    left: var(--position, $position);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    pointer-events: none;
  
}

.slider-button {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: $white;
    padding: .5rem;
    border-radius: 100vw;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: var(--position, $position);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 100;
    box-shadow: $box-shadow;
}
```

app.js

````
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

document.querySelector(".slider").addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  container.style.setProperty(`--position`, `${e.target.value}%`);
});```
````